# Deserialize XML to list of lists

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Given the following code used to serialize:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = true, ElementName = "ReportSpec")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ReportSpec{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Reports")]
    public ReportsHolder MyHolder { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Version { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReportsHolder{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public List<AlertsReport> AlertsReportList { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public List<DeviceHistoryReport> DeviceHistoryReportList { get; set; }

    public ReportsHolder(){
        this.AlertsReportList = new List<AlertsReport>();
        this.DeviceHistoryReport = new List<DeviceHistoryReport>();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseReport{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string FilterMode { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class AlertsReport : BaseReport{

    public AlertsReportFilters Filters { get; set; }

    public AlertsReport(){
        Filters = new AlertsReportFilters();
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class AlertsReportFilters{

    public string AlertSource { get; set; }

    public byte? Scope { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeScope(){
        return Scope != null;
    }

    public ushort? DeviceID { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceID(){
        return DeviceID != null;
    }

    public string DeviceType { get; set; }

    public byte? DeviceGroup { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceGroup(){
        return DeviceGroup != null;
    }

    public uint? DeviceFacility { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceFacility(){
        return DeviceFacility != null;
    }

    public uint? DeviceRegion { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceRegion(){
        return DeviceRegion != null;
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class DeviceHistoryReport : BaseReport{

    public ushort? DeviceID { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDeviceID(){
        return DeviceID != null;
    }
}
```

Which ends up serializing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReportSpec Version="4.5" Username="My Name">
  <Reports>
    <AlertsReportList FilterMode="Container" Destination="someone@somewhere.com" Format="PDF">
      <Filters>
        <AlertSource>Frankenstein</AlertSource>
        <Scope>0</Scope>
      </Filters>
    </AlertsReportList>

    <AlertsReportList FilterMode="Container" Destination="someone.else@somewhere.com" Format="XLS">
      <Filters>
        <DeviceGroup>12</DeviceGroup>
      </Filters>
    </AlertsReportList>

    <DeviceHistoryReportList FilterMode="Container" Destination="\\path\on\my\network" Format="DOC">
      <Filters>
        <DeviceID>255</DeviceID>
      </Filters>
    </DeviceHistoryReportList>

    <DeviceHistoryReportList FilterMode="Container" Destination="mr.executive@somewhere.com" Format="TXT">
      <Filters>
        <DeviceID>44</DeviceID>
      </Filters>
    </DeviceHistoryReportList>
  </Reports>
</ReportSpec>
```

I am wanting to get a list of each ReportList object to process later in my application, but I am getting a "Type 'ReportSpec' is not enumerable" error in my foreach loop:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\TestFile.xml");
TextReader reader = streamReader;
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportSpec));
var list = (ReportSpec)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
foreach (var report in list){    // <-- error is here
    //re-direct the report (AlertsReportList, DeviceHistoryReportList) for processing
}
```

Is what I want even possible, and if so, where am I screwing up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate the lists within the ReportSpec. i.e.

```
foreach (var report in list.MyHolder.AlertReportsList)
{
    // ...
}

foreach (var report in list.MyHolder.DeviceHistoryReportsList)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: is there a way to implement a `switch` statement based on `report.GetType()`, or would I be looking at re-designing my serializer (which I'm not really opposed to at the moment)?

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do this - could you clarify? The loop variable report in the above should be of type AlertReport in the first loop and DeviceHistoryReport in the second.

Comment: Perhaps it's a personal thing.  I currently have 12 different type of reports to process (so where there is AlertsReportsList and DeviceHistoryReportsList now, there will be 10 more to add) with more on the horizon, and using a `foreach` statement looks more "clunky" to me than a `switch` statement.  Yes, they accomplish the same thing, but `switch` has always bee more sleek-feeling to me (unless there is a better way than either `foreach` or `switch`).

Answer (score 0):

`ReportSpec` is just a simple class; And, It doesn't implement `IEnumerable` interface which means you can't iterate that class using `foreach` loop

To redirect your Reports for further processing, just use below code snippet

```
var reportSpec= (ReportSpec)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
Processing(reportSpec.MyHolder.AlertsReportList, reportSpec.MyHolder.DeviceHistoryReportList);
```